# How to perform live java debugging without restarting the application

Tags: java, debugging

I want to debug a running java application **without** having to restart it with the remote debugging arguments `java -agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=8000,suspend=n`

I was wondering if there is a way to debug a running java application. If possible attach to jdb, else what options do I have to investigate a live application?

Have a nasty issue where the application is "running" and providing *some* functionality, but the other half of it is not.
No logs are emmited from the broken half so I'd like to see "what is happening inside".
Restarting the process "fixes" the problem so I'd like to avoid that.

Comment: I would do a remote connect with IntelliJ, as long as the debug port was open.

Answer (score 1):

You can get a interactive debug console with:
[`jhsdb clhsdb --pid <PID>`](https://github.com/IceHe/lib/blob/master/java/cmd/jhsdb.md)

This is NOT the same as the jdwp session but should give you SOMETHING if restarting with it loaded is out of the question/difficult.

I was able get what I needed to debug the application without a `jdwp` session via:

`jps` to get the **PID**

`jstack -l -e <PID>` to get the stack trace

and then

`jmap -dump:file=iamsick.hprof` to get the heap

I could use this to safely explore the application as a frozen "snapshot"

I also played around with: `jhsdb clhsdb --pid <PID>` but be warned that you are poking a potentially fragile/volatile application which might result in it crashing and you loosing the chance to investigate.

Recommend you dump the heap first before poking around

Comment: Capturing stack trace and heap dumps are useful troubleshooting techniques for sure, but they are not a way to connect a debugger to a running Java application like your question requested. I would recommend to edit the question to expand its scope.